# NotificationCenter requestAuthorization alert failing to display when returning from the background

Tags: swift, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter

I am requesting authorisation from the user to send notifications, and when doing so the alert pops up with the default notification message and `Don't allow` / `Allow` buttons, as expected.

However, if I background the app **without having made a selection**, then reopen the app again I cannot get the alert to display a second time.

I can force a call to requestAuthorization again, and I correctly see in the completion block that the authorisation request is false (as no prior selection was made).

```
let options: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
     // granted = false
}
```

But why would the alert not display again?

Any clarity on this would be appreciated.

As a side note, I have noticed that when requesting a users location, I am prevented from even minimising the app until a choice has been made!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently designed to be this way.

When sending the app to the background granted is automatically set as false.

> The first time your app makes this authorization request, the system
> prompts the user to grant or deny the request and records the user’s
> response. Subsequent authorization requests don’t prompt the user.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications